# IIS Reverse Proxy on top site

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-8, windows-server-2016

I have a site (ex: a.domain.com) with multiple applications inside (ex: a.domain.com/App1, a.domain.com/AppX).

I need to figure out how to do a reverse proxy on the top site, only when the people try to access a.domain.com. If someone wants to access a.domain.com/App1 the reverse proxy will have no effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply build a reverse proxy using ARR, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing and then make sure your rules exclude those applications. What's the difficulty here?

Comment: The problem is that this site already has 288 applications inside (one per client i have) and grows every month.

Comment: Working on a site with two applications has almost no difference from a site with 288 applications, if you do know enough about regular expressions and IIS URL Rewrite module. So again, edit your question to be more specific, or no one is able to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know how did you set the reverse proxy?

In IIS, we usually use URL rewrite rule to build the reverse proxy.

If you only require  reverse proxy rule only take effect on the root www.doamin.com. Then you should add an   `<add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />`condition pattern in your rule or include all folder/URL under the top site. Otherwise you have to use regex expression to exclude all 288 applications manually. IIS won't be able to detect sub-application collection and add them to URL rewrite rule automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the answer i was looking for.